# why there is no output

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote an example on Javascript `function` [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/penoqomiqe/edit?html,output), but there is no output, how can I solve this mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function student(name,id,level,phone){
        var name, id, level, phone;
        this.name= name;
        this.id= id;
        this.level= level;
        this.phone= phone;}
        function myFunction(){
        var stud = new student("khaled al gamd","110_35_1353","three",0501607419);
        var name= stud.(name);
        var id= stud.(id);
        var level= stud.(level);
        var phone= stud.(phone);
        document.write (name);
        document.write (id);
        document.write (phone);
    }
    <p id="result"><\/p>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=myFunction();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything, its directly writing to the document, which is a bad practice by the way. Not to mention all the other problems with your code. For example in your `student` constructor your `var` line is overwriting your passed arguments

Comment: Your syntax is full of errors, are you sure it's compiling and not throwing any errors?

Comment: Sorry I am way too dumb here, what `stud.(name)` means?

Comment: @DawidPura It isn't you, that is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write out that paragraph tag if you want to create it through JavaScript:

```
function student(name, id, level, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.level = level;
    this.phone = phone;
}
function myFunction() {
    var stud = new student("khaled al gamd", "110_35_1353", "three", 0501607419);
    var name = stud.name;
    var id = stud.id;
    var level = stud.level;
    var phone = stud.phone;
    return name + "<br>" + id + "<br>" + phone;
}
document.write('<p id="result">  </p>');
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myFunction();
```

For help on JavaScript, you can try JSHint:

http://jshint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript with html together.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="result">

<script type="text/javascript">
function student(name,id,level,phone){
this.name= name;
this.id= id;
this.level= level;
this.phone= phone;
}

function myFunction(){
var stud = new student("khaled al gamd","110_35_1353","three",0501607419);
var name= stud.name;
var id= stud.id;
var level= stud.level;
var phone= stud.phone;
document.write(name);
document.write(id);
document.write(phone);}

myFunction();
</script>
</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct, but neither of them explain why they are correct so here's a little explanation.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p id="result"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function student(name,id,level,phone){
   var name, id, level, phone;
   this.name= name;
   this.id= id;
   this.level= level;
   this.phone= phone;
}

function myFunction(){
  var stud = new student("khaled al gamd","110_35_1353","three",0501607419);
  var name= stud.name;
  var id= stud.id;
  var level= stud.level;
  var phone= stud.phone;
  return name + id + phone;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=myFunction();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Now, there were a few issues with your example. Firstly, you were trying to access attributes of the student object like this: `stud.(name)` which is not valid syntax. The correct syntax for this is: `stud.name`.

Secondly, you were declaring html elements inside your script tags. Everything inside the script tags should be valid javascript, which this is not. You have two alternatives, one is to move that line outside the script tags (inside the body, above your script or it won't be created until after the script is run), the other is to create the elements with javascript as in the answer by @Emil S. Jørgensen.

Thirdly, you were trying to set the inner html of the element to the result of the function, but the function did not return anything to display. Rather it tried to write directly to the document. This will give you some output, but it will not be inside the element that you are aiming for. Instead what you need to do is to return some valid html from the function (although this does not necessarily have to contain any html elements).

Correct these issues and it should work as expected. One side note though, your code is not well formatted which makes it harder to read and harder to spot problems. I would suggest you take care in formatting your code in future.